# On start of app scroll to last element of listview in flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, scroll

I want listview should scroll to last element of listview on start of app. How can i do it? i tried scrolling in initState but that raised an error. I used this code in initState:-

```
_scrollController.animateTo(
              _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
              curve: Curves.easeOut,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            );
```

the error i got was:-

```
ScrollController not attached to any scroll views.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you initialize the `ScrollController` just pass a large value for the `initialScrollOffset`

Comment: Is this possible without a big jump on initial load?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the ScroolControlller with large value like this.

```
    ScrollController myScrollController=ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 10000.0);
```